# Any tool which can reverse json to java class definition

Tags: java

I need to generate java class definition from json data. Is there any tool to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this google project looks like it does what you are asking for.
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo